# ¿Cómo utilizar momentjs con fechas en Español?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, momentjs

He utilizado

```javascript
moment.defineLocale('es', {
      months: 'Enero_Febrero_Marzo_Abril_Mayo_Junio_Julio_Agosto_Septiembre_Octubre_Noviembre_Diciembre'.split('_'),
      monthsShort: 'Enero._Feb._Mar_Abr._May_Jun_Jul._Ago_Sept._Oct._Nov._Dec.'.split('_'),
      weekdays: 'Domingo_Lunes_Martes_Miercoles_Jueves_Viernes_Sabado'.split('_'),
      weekdaysShort: 'Dom._Lun._Mar._Mier._Jue._Vier._Sab.'.split('_'),
      weekdaysMin: 'Do_Lu_Ma_Mi_Ju_Vi_Sa'.split('_')
})
```

De acuerdo al último pull request de `momentjs` pero me sigue saliendo este warning en el inspector

```bash
Deprecation warning: use moment.updateLocale(localeName, config) to change an existing locale. moment.defineLocale(localeName, config) should only be used for creating a new locale See http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/define-locale/ for more info.
```

Alguien tiene la solución o alguna otra forma de usar moment pero con fechas en español

Comment: No funciona. Sigue saliendo en inglés.

Comment: Colocando moment.defineLocale sale ya en español pero sigo viendo el warning. A lo mejor hay ya otra forma de definir el idioma

Comment: @JackNavaRow versión 2.19.2

Comment: `moment.lang("es");` te da error por que ya existe el idioma español cargado, por lo tanto debes solo notificarle, en tu carpeta momment debes tener dentro una carpeta locale y alli se encuentran todos los idiomas, de hecho el error te lo dijo `should only be used for creating a new locale `

Comment: Ya probé con moment.lang('es') pero el warning: moment.lang('es') Is deprecated. Use moment.locale instead

Comment: intentalo moment.locale('es')

Answer (score 4):

segun la [documentacion](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) para la version que tienes solo debes agregar o instalar  el paquete de idioma para moment en la que trabajas(generalmente viene instalado cuando haces el **`npm install`**)

```js
moment.locale('es');
console.log(moment(Date.now()).fromNow()); 
console.log(moment(Date.now())); 
console.log(moment(Date.now()).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/locale/es.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Al momento de importar la librería importas también el idioma:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';
```

También puedes optar antes de cada conversión especificar el idioma:

```
moment.locale('es');
fecha_convertida = moment(fecha).format('LL');
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza:

```javascript
import moment from 'moment/moment'
```

En vez de:

```javascript
import moment from 'moment'
```

Una extraña razón.